# Can an office addin / app (non-com) add a formula to Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-addins, vba

I am wondering if an Office addin (the new term for "app"), that is a Non-COM Office Addin (introduced in Office 2013) would be able to add a formula to Excel?

As I read the documentation, it is only possible to add a taskpane or to access the document. However, I cannot add a formula which will call a (Javascript) function from my addin and then puts the return value in the excel cell.

So e.g. if I would like to create the formula
=MultiplyBi3(value)

I would need to create an Excel RTD Server with a COM Addin, and cannot use Office Apps.. sad but true?

Comment: Perhaps you should explore this under the [office-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-js) tag...?

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript API can add a formula to a cell or a Defined Name formula (JS calls them Named Items) but cannot create a UDF function, and certainly cannot create a RTD server either (but neither can VBA).